# Quartz .NET - quartz doesn't work when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

> The job does not run on the server. Everything works locally in the
> development version

```
NOT STARTED.
      Currently in standby mode.
      Number of jobs executed: 0
      Using thread pool 'Quartz.Simpl.DefaultThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
      Using job-store 'Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
     
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5236||INFO|Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory|Quartz scheduler 'QuartzScheduler' initialized 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5236||INFO|Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory|Quartz scheduler version: 3.3.3.0 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5617||INFO|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Adding 1 jobs, 1 triggers. 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5617||INFO|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Adding job: DEFAULT.SendEmailQualityControlJob 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5617||DEBUG|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Scheduling job: DEFAULT.SendEmailQualityControlJob with trigger: DEFAULT.SendEmailQualityControlJob-trigger 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5874||DEBUG|Quartz.ContainerConfigurationProcessor|Rescheduling job: DEFAULT.SendEmailQualityControlJob with updated trigger: DEFAULT.SendEmailQualityControlJob-trigger 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.5874||INFO|Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler|Scheduler QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started. 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.9056||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.9056||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Hosting environment: Production 
    2021-09-07 08:51:30.9196||INFO|Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime|Content root path: C:\IISPATCH\TLC 
    2021-09-07 08:51:44.2154||INFO|AppForSellers.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel|Użytkownik .
```

c#

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
              {
                  services.AddQuartz(q =>
                  {
                      //    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionScopedJobFactory();

                      //    // Register the job, loading the schedule from configuration
                      //    q.AddJobAndTrigger<SendEmailQualityControlJob>(hostContext.Configuration);
                      //});

                      //services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);

                      q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

                      // Create a "key" for the job
                      var jobKey = new JobKey("SendEmailQualityControlJob");

                      // Register the job with the DI container
                      q.AddJob<SendEmailQualityControlJob>(opts => opts.WithIdentity(jobKey));

                      // Create a trigger for the job
                      q.AddTrigger(opts => opts
                        .ForJob(jobKey) // link to the SendEmailQualityControlJob
                        .WithIdentity("SendEmailQualityControlJob-trigger") // give the trigger a unique name
                        .WithCronSchedule("00 50 08 ? * TUE *"));
                      //cronExpression: "00 08 12 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *"));

                  });
                  services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
              }).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();


              }).UseNLog();
```

I used a very good example
https://andrewlock.net/using-quartz-net-with-asp-net-core-and-worker-services/

I don't know why it doesn't work on the server?

Comment: First thing to check on a server is an logging. Second is to check permissions.

Comment: Any hints regarding server permissions, I can ask

Comment: What does  .StartNow() on the trigger do? Does it actually executes it?

Comment: So it works fine locally only after publishing it stops working

Comment: Is the server configured to different time zone than you local machine? That would make the trigger fire on different time than what you would observe as 08:50 Tuesday.

Comment: Server configured on the same time zone than my local machine

Comment: Locally, it is perfectly configured in Cron. Every time the scheduler starts a task and sends e-mails to subscribers.

Comment: When sending e-mails, I download data from the sql database. Does it matter if it requires additional configuration on the server or in the application in Quartz.net?

Comment: I tested every 20 seconds and it works - the problem on the server is with the cron setting